# Is there any difference between First Class Functions and Callback Functions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, callback, first-class-functions

Are there any differences between first class functions and callback functions in javascript? I thought that first class functions were functions that were treated as regular variables and can be passed as arguments. Aren't callback functions the same?

Comment: A callback is just a use case of a function passed into another function

Comment: There is not distinction between "first-class functions" and "other-class functions". The term *first-class* describes how (all) functions work in general in the JavaScript language.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, all functions are first class in javascript and can be passed as objects. That's why callbacks are even possible. If you couldn't pass a function as an object there would be no way for another function (in a different scope) to use your passed function.

An example of using a first class function directly and as a callback.

```
function callsback(callbackFunc) {
    callbackFunc()
}

function firstClass() {
    console.log("I was called");
}

firstClass(); // "I was called"
callsback(firstClass); // "I was called"
```

Answer (score 1):

A language is said to have first class function if they are treated as variables. So it means that we can return a function, we can pass a function as an argument and we can assign a function as a value to a variable.

Callback function is also a first class function going by this definition because it is also passed as an argument. But Callback functions are used to specifically handle asynchronous tasks in a synchronous single threaded language like JavaScript.